# Wordpress uses MySQL fulltext search?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, full-text-search

I have a PHP/MySQL installation. I'm working on a program that uses a MySQL Fulltext search. I want to reduce the min word length to three. I know I can do this by changing the `ft_min_word_length` global variable and restarting MySQL.

My problem is that the MySQL server is running several other databases, including two Wordpress blogs. If I change that global variable, will this affect/muck up the Wordpress posts search? What algorithm does Wordpress use? Does it use MySQL FULLTEXT?

Is there a way to set `ft_min_word_length` for only one database? Should I worry about it?

I'm using MySql 5.0.5, PHP 5, and Wordpress 2.8 on IIS 6.0

Answer (score 4):

You can find out if full text index is being used...

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX, COLUMN_NAME, CARDINALITY, NULLABLE
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE index_type LIKE 'FULLTEXT%' ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

> > Is there a way to set ft_min_word_length for only one database?

No.

Comment: Thank you.

Turns out Wordpress doesn't use Fulltext search, so I'm in the clear.